# How to prove that the linear independency of $f_{i}$ from $C^{n-1}\left [ a, b \right ]$ to $C\left [ a, b \right ]$

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove that

> if $f_{1}, f_{2}, ..., f_{n}$ are linearly independent in $C^{n-1}\left [ a, b \right ]$,
>
> then they will also be linearly independent in $C\left [ a, b \right ]$.

Comment: Vectors of $\mathcal{C}^{n-1} \big( [a,b] \big)$ are also vectors of $\mathcal{C} \big( [a,b] \big)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion $$I:C^{n-1}[a,b]\to C[a,b]$$ tautologically defined by $I(f)=f$
is a linear map which is injective. Therefore if 
$$C[a,b]\ni 0=\sum\lambda_i f_i=\sum\lambda_iI(f_i)=I(\sum\lambda_if_i)$$

we must have $\sum\lambda_if_i=0\in C^{n-1}[a,b]$.  If $f_i$ are linearly independent on $C^{n-1}[a,b]$ then $\lambda_i=0\forall i$, so $f_i$ are independent as vectors of $C[a,b]$

This works in general if you replace $I:C^{n-1}[a,b]\to C[a,b]$ whith any linear injection $f:V\to W$ between vector spaces.